# Problems redirecting NUnit assembly version (what is [AssemblyName].temp.config?)

Tags: .net, nunit, assembly-resolution, testdriven.net

I am using some of the testing libraries from Sharp Architecture which make use of NUnit 2.5.0 while the rest of my project uses NUnit 2.5.1 so I placed an assembly redirect in my test project app config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="nunit.framework"
                                  publicKeyToken="96d09a1eb7f44a77" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="2.5.0.9122"
                                 newVersion="2.5.1.9189"/>
            </dependentAssembly>        
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

I am still getting an assembly redirect version:

```
TestCase ''
failed: Could not load file or assembly 'nunit.framework, Version=2.5.0.9122, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=96d09a1eb7f44a77' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
    System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'nunit.framework, Version=2.5.0.9122, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=96d09a1eb7f44a77' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
    File name: 'nunit.framework, Version=2.5.0.9122, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=96d09a1eb7f44a77'
```

Enabling my Fusion ErrorLog I see this:

```
=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = nunit.framework, Version=2.5.0.9122, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=96d09a1eb7f44a77
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/code/Samples/PersistencePatterns/app/PersistencePatterns.Tests/bin/Debug
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
Calling assembly : SharpArch.Testing.NUnit, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b5f559ae0ac4e006.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\code\Samples\PersistencePatterns\app\PersistencePatterns.Tests\bin\Debug\PersistencePatterns.Tests.dll.temp.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: nunit.framework, Version=2.5.0.9122, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=96d09a1eb7f44a77
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/code/Samples/PersistencePatterns/app/PersistencePatterns.Tests/bin/Debug/nunit.framework.DLL.
WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Revision Number
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing terminated.
```

What gives?  What is this temp.config file that its looking for?  Why isn't it looking in my actual config?

Well no matter, I added the following to my post-build events:

```
copy $(ProjectDir)App.config $(TargetDir)\$(TargetFileName).temp.config
```

Everything gets copied fine, but as soon as I run tests with Testdriven.NET the file disappears.

Can anyone give me a clue as to whats going on?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried copying the App.config of the class library without the ".temp" part?

```
copy $(ProjectDir)App.config $(TargetDir)\$(TargetFileName).config
```

**EDIT:** The "*.temp.config" seems to be generated by the TestDriven.NET, as `[stated in the release notes of version 2.3][1]`

Comment: That's what Visual studio does already.  I have verified that this functionality isn't broken for some reason by checking that the file exists.  I've never seen a temp extension like that before though.

Comment: You're right, I was convinced that it would only do that for an executable and not a class library. My mistake. The "*.temp.config" seems to be generated by the TestDriven.NET though, as stated in the release notes of version 2.3 (http://www.testdriven.net/downloads/ReleaseNotes.html).